# How do I become a Scholar of the Correspondence?

Tags: fallen-london

Now that my Watchful Quality is reaching past level 80, I find myself seeking my fortune at both The Forgotten Quarter and the University.

However, it seems that to prove my worth to the University, I must become a stated Scholar of the Correspondence.

But despite my many wanderings of the Forgotten Quarter and my lengthy casual study of the Correspondence, I still haven't obtained this prestige.

**How might I become a proper Scholar of the Correspondence?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The content for becoming a *Scholar of the Correspondence* **has changed.** It now involves becoming a skilled archaeologist, going on repeated expeditions, and then finding and examining the Correspondence Stones.

The first step is straightforward: go on expeditions until your *Archaeologist* quality reaches 3. This will take around four expeditions.

1. In the Forgotten Quarter, use the **Prepare for an Expedition in the Forgotten Quarter** storylet (which unlocks at *Watchful 60*) to pick up expedition supplies; those supplies will cost you Whispered Secrets, Appalling Secrets, *Connected: Docks* and a little Rostygold, or cold, hard Echoes. Feel free to give yourself a generous buffer of supplies: you may need them, and any leftovers can be used on the next expedition.
2. There's one more storylet in here, which I don't have the text for and can't recall precisely: to gain *Archaeologist 1*, which allows you to begin your first expedition, you must first spend ~200 Whispered Secrets, ~20 Appalling Secrets, and some other resources to gain a basic understanding of the Forgotten Quarter.
3. Once you have enough supplies, play the **Begin an Expedition** storylet (inside the storylet for preparing for an expedition). This will let you pick a specific expedition; harder expeditions require more supplies and a higher *Archaeologist* level. The first expedition, **Seek a thieves' cache**, requires *Connected: Criminals 3*.
4. Once you're on the expedition, the storylets there will let you advance slowly or quickly, depending on how many Expedition Supplies you're willing to risk and how difficult you want the *Watchful* check to be. Occasionally, the ever-changing quality *Airs of the Forgotten Quarter* will allow some other storylets; these are invariably good things, but some of them cost Fate/Nex. The **Shrine of the Deep Blue Heaven** (and later expeditions) will also have Rivals; if their progress reaches 10, they'll need to be driven off: this will cost 10 Expedition Supplies, plus some other resources depending on which rival it is.
5. When you complete the expedition, you'll find a random treasure, and your *Archaeologist* quality will usually increase. (*Archaeologist* is not one of the usual qualities that has its progress tracked; I don't know if it racks up change points as normal, or has a different mechanism for improvement. I found that my *Archaeologist* quality increased by one on every second expedition. I always chose the most difficult expedition available to me, so I don't know if the difficulty of the expedition changes the odds or amount of *Archaeologist* increase. As a side note, I have just increased *Archaeologist* from 3 to 4 using an expedition that only required 2.)

The second step is a reprise of the first: go on an expedition to find the **Tomb of Seven**, and get there before your Rivals do; you will need *Archaeologist 3* and at least 30 Expedition Supplies. You will have two rivals on this expedition: Dr. Orthos and Virginia.

Once you complete the Tomb of Seven (which finishes with a *Dangerous* check), you'll have the Correspondence Stones. These stones open up two new storylets in the Forgotten Quarter. One of them is called **The Secrets of the Stones**, and I can't recall the other one's name (it had a gold border), because it became unavailable after I played the first one. Play this storylet, and you'll become a *Scholar of the Correspondence.*

**Note:** There are no requirements beyond *Watchful 60* and *Connected: Criminals 3* to become a *Scholar of the Correspondence*. Once you have those minimum qualities, everything else is about how many actions and resources you're willing to spend, and succeeding on enough *Watchful* checks to complete expeditions. You may want to have a decent stash of Sudden Insights (the *Watchful* second-chance item) to allow you to reliably advance an expedition quickly if you're falling behind your Rivals.

Comment: I can verify that this is indeed the method nowadays, since I've just finished the process myself! (but was too lazy to get around to writing an answer :P)

Comment: @RedRiderX I don't suppose you can fill in some of the bits I've forgotten, like the payment for Archaeologist 1 or the gold-bordered storylet after you acquire the stones but before you're a Scholar?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't take very good notes on either of those points in the process. My apologies.

Comment: Ah, seems my answer was out of date - I'll delete it. It's a shame the wikis for Fallen London haven't updated.